# Test instance method of mailer - Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def venues
    @venues ||= Venue.find(VENUE_MAP.values)
  end
end
```

How can I test venues, if:

```
ReportMailer.new => nil
```

How is this behavior called? is ReportMailer an abstract class?

Comment: How do you get `ReportMailer.new #=> nil`? It seems weird to me

Comment: Is weird to me too. I created a new Rails 2.3. app to isolate causes, but I am having the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extracted methods to module and then, included and extended it:

```
class ReportMailer
  include ReportMailer::PrivateMethods
  extend  ReportMailer::PrivateMethods
...
```

In `app/models/report_mailer/private_methods.rb`:

```
module ReportMailer::PrivateMethods
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

All the methods you define in `ReportMailer` can be called as class methods

```
ReportMailer.venues
```

To deliver the email

```
ReportMailer.venues.deliver
```

[Read](http://smsohan.com/blog/2011/01/28/actionmailer-3-why-do-you-call-instance/)

Comment: I am in Rails 2.3, I tried `ReportMailer.venues` but it throws error.

Comment: Try `ReportMailer.deliver_venues`